# Display value of input range slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input, output

I have a simple input slider and I'd like to display the value the slider is currently on below it.

I thought I had this working with the following script but it broke everything else on the page that uses Javascript.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var slider = document.getElementById("deposit-input");
    var output = document.getElementById("deposit-value");
    output.innerHTML = slider.value;

    slider.oninput = function() {
      output.innerHTML = this.value;
    }
});
```

What's wrong with this or is there a better/easier way of displaying the value on the page?

Thanks in advance!

```js
/* ==========================================================================
   #NAVIGATION
   ========================================================================== */
 
/* 
 * Creates classes to enable responsive navigation.
 */

// Wait for the DOM to be ready (all elements printed on page regardless if 
// loaded or not).

$(function() {

 // Bind a click event to anything with the class "toggle-nav".
 $('.page-head__toggle').click(function() {
  if ($('body').hasClass('show-nav')) {
   $('body').removeClass('show-nav').addClass('hide-nav');

   setTimeout(function() {
    $('body').removeClass('hide-nav');
   }, 800);

  } else {
   $('body').removeClass('hide-nav').addClass('show-nav');
  }
  // Deactivate the default behavior of going to the next page on click.
  return false;
 });
});


/* 
 * Sliding Line.
 */
 
$(function() {
  var $el,
    leftPos,
    newWidth,
    $mainNav = $(".site-nav__list");

  $mainNav.append("<div class='site-nav__line'></div>");
  var $magicLine = $(".site-nav__line"),
    $currentMenu = $(".current-menu-item");

  $magicLine
    .width($currentMenu.length ? $currentMenu.width() : 0)
    .css("left", $currentMenu.length ? $currentMenu.find("a").position().left : 0)
    .data("origLeft", $magicLine.position().left)
    .data("origWidth", $magicLine.width());

  var hoverOut;

  $(".site-nav__list li a").hover(function() {
      clearTimeout(hoverOut);
    
      $el = $(this);
      leftPos = $el.position().left;
      newWidth = $el.parent().width();

      if (!$magicLine.width()) {
        $magicLine.stop().hide().css({
            left: leftPos,
            width: newWidth
          }).fadeIn(100);
      } else {
        $magicLine.stop().animate({
          opacity: 1,
          left: leftPos,
          width: newWidth
        });
      }
    },
    function() {
      hoverOut = setTimeout(function() {
        if (!$currentMenu.length) {
          $magicLine.fadeOut(100, function() {
            $magicLine.css({
              left: $magicLine.data("origLeft"),
              width: $magicLine.data("origWidth")
            });
          });
        } else {
          $magicLine.stop().animate({
            left: $magicLine.data("origLeft"),
            width: $magicLine.data("origWidth")
          });
        }
      }, 100);
    }
  );
});





/* ==========================================================================
   #Simple Accordion
   ========================================================================== */

$('.accordion').find('.accordion__title').click(function(){
 $(this).toggleClass('open');
 $(this).next().slideToggle('fast');
});





/* ==========================================================================
   #INPUT SLIDER
   ========================================================================== */

/* 
 * Simple version. This code just uses the `<input type="range" />` element and
 * displays the value on the page.
 */

$(document).ready(function(){
 var slider = document.getElementById("deposit-input");
 var output = document.getElementById("deposit-value");
 output.innerHTML = slider.value;
 
 slider.oninput = function() {
   output.innerHTML = this.value;
 }
});





/* ==========================================================================
   #SLICK
   ========================================================================== */
 
/* 
 * Creates classes to enable responsive navigation.
 */

$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.slick-slider').slick({
  adaptiveHeight: true,
  arrows: false,
  dots: true,
  infinite: false,
  fade: true,
  cssEase: 'ease-out',
  speed: 300
 });
});

/* 
 * Creates classes to enable responsive navigation.
 */
 
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.slick-carousel').slick({
   centerMode: true,
   centerPadding: '0',
   slidesToShow: 3,
   arrows: false,
   dots: true,
   responsive: [
     {
       breakpoint: 960,
       settings: {
         centerMode: true,
         centerPadding: '120px',
         slidesToShow: 1
       }
     },
     {
       breakpoint: 600,
       settings: {
         centerMode: true,
         centerPadding: '60px',
         slidesToShow: 1
       }
     },
     {
       breakpoint: 480,
       settings: {
         centerMode: true,
         centerPadding: '30px',
         slidesToShow: 1
       }
     }
   ]
 });
});

/* 
 * Slideshow form (for apply page)
 */

$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.slick-form').slick({
  adaptiveHeight: true,
  arrows: true,
  appendArrows: $('.slick-form-arrows'),
  prevArrow: '<span class="btn">Go Back</span>',
  nextArrow: '<span class="btn">Next Slide</span>',
  dots: false,
  infinite: false
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="form-group">
  <label class="label form-group__title">Slider (browser) <span class="required">*</span></label>
  <div class="form-group__controls">
    <div class="slider align-center">
      <input type="range" min="0" max="100" value="50" class="slider__input" id="deposit-input" />
      <p class="slider__value">Amount: <strong>£<span id="deposit-value"></span></strong></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Maybe you should try adding back some of the "broken" code. Your snippet is working and we can't guess what's wrong with the other parts of your code.

Comment: Added the entire JS file. Thought the entire page html might be a bit OTT!

Comment: The snippet throws an error now. :)

Comment: Ah ok, I couldn't see anything in the browser console. Any idea what it is?

Comment: The error, according to your html, starts here: **$mainNav = $(".site-nav__list")**

Comment: It throws an error because some elements needed by your script are not in the HTML.

Comment: Odd that element (the main nav) is on the page :/

Comment: No, `.site-nav__list` is not in the snippet.